# `zip` operator to iterate on multiple container in a sign

Tags: c++, template, iterator, c++17, variadic

I worked out a `zip` operator similar to [Python's](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), because I didn't find one in `std`. It allows to use range-based `for` loops to iterate at once over several equal-length containers (arrays,  counters... anything that has an iterator and a static length). It should be safe (never exceed the iterator's capacity), be able to modify the content of the container in-place when possible, and have no run-time overhead compared to manually incrementing the iterators.

Some things still look a bit fishy to me and I also wonder if all my naming/implementation choices adhere the `std` look-and-feel. Examples of use:

```
  std::array a = {1,2,3,4};
  std::array b = {4,3,2,1};

  for (auto [i, j, k] : zip(a, b, a)) {
    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;
    i = 42; // we can overwrite the values of a
  }

  //// This one doesn't work yet:
  // for (auto [i, j] : zip(a, {4, 3, 2, 1})) {
  //   std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
  // }
```

With it comes a simple `range` class that allows to include counters in the iterations:

```
  // x takes the value of array a, and i counts from 0 to 3
  for (auto [x, i] : zip(a, range<4>())) {
    std::cout << i << " " << x << std::endl;
  }
```

Note here that the arguments to `zip` aren't necessarily *l-values*.

Here is my implementation:

```
// inductive case
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct zip : public zip<Ts...> {
  static_assert(std::tuple_size<T>::value == std::tuple_size<zip<Ts...>>::value,
                "Cannot zip over structures of different sizes");

  using head_value_type = std::tuple<typename T::value_type&>;
  using tail_value_type = typename zip<Ts...>::value_type;
  using value_type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<head_value_type>(),
                                             std::declval<tail_value_type>()));

  zip(T& t, Ts&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
  zip(T& t, Ts&&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
  zip(T&& t, Ts&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
  zip(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}

  struct iterator {
    using head_iterator = typename T::iterator;
    using tail_iterator = typename zip<Ts...>::iterator;

    head_iterator head;
    tail_iterator tail;

    bool operator!=(iterator& that) { return head != that.head; }
    void operator++() { ++head; ++tail; }

    value_type operator*() {
      return std::tuple_cat<head_value_type, tail_value_type>(*head, *tail);
    }

    iterator(head_iterator h, tail_iterator t) : head(h), tail(t) {}
  };

  iterator begin() { return iterator(t_.begin(), zip<Ts...>::begin()); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(t_.end(), zip<Ts...>::end()); }
  T& t_;
};

// base case
template<typename T>
struct zip<T> {
  using value_type = std::tuple<typename T::value_type&>;
  using iterator = typename T::iterator;
  zip(T&& t) : t_(t) {};
  zip(T& t) : t_(t) {};
  iterator begin() { return t_.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return t_.end(); }
private:
  T& t_;
};

// must implement tuple_size to check size equality
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct std::tuple_size<zip<T, Ts...>> {
  static constexpr int value = std::tuple_size<T>::value;
};
```

What looks fishy/over-complicated:

- the constructors to cover all kinds of arguments (l/r-value/references)
- the mangling of tuple types
- bonus: why doesn't my second example compile?

For completeness, here is my implementation of the `range` class:

```
template<class T, T BEG, T END, T STEP>
struct Range {
  Range() {};
  using iterator = Range;
  using value_type = T;

  bool operator!=(iterator that) { return this->val_ < that.val_; }
  void operator++() { val_ += STEP; }
  int& operator*() { return val_;}

  iterator begin() { return *this; }
  iterator end() { return Range(END); }
private:
  Range(int val) : val_(val) {}
  T val_ = BEG;
};

template<class T, T BEG, T END, T STEP>
struct std::tuple_size<Range<T, BEG, END, STEP>> {
  static constexpr int value = (END - BEG) / STEP;
};

template<class T, T BEG, T END, T STEP>
static auto range() { return Range<T, BEG, END, STEP>(); };

template<int BEG, int END, int STEP=1>
static auto range() { return Range<int, BEG, END, STEP>(); };

template<int END>
static auto range() { return Range<int, 0, END, 1>(); };
```

Any feedback will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This looks nice. Can you post a small example program that uses it, so that we can verify that it compiles and runs correctly?

Comment: Hello and thanks. I had some examples at the top of the post; the whole code should compile if you put the 3 chunks in the right order. Would you like to see some other ones? or more concrete use cases?

Comment: I mean something like this https://wandbox.org/permlink/XrF354DmZirvbpUl

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `zip`

Right now, your `zip` uses the tuple protocol.  It probably makes more sense to use the range protocol instead, to support cases like this:

```
std::vector a{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector b{5, 6, 7, 8};
for (auto [x, y] : zip(a, b)) {
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
}
```

These constructors:

```
zip(T& t, Ts&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
zip(T& t, Ts&&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
zip(T&& t, Ts&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
zip(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) : zip<Ts...>(ts...), t_(t) {}
```

mandate that all arguments other than the first have the same.  You also convert everything to lvalues, because an id-expression that refer to an rvalue reference is an lvalue (!) — this is because the original purpose of rvalue references were to capture rvalues and treat them like normal objects, not to forward rvalues.

The `iterator` class is also some required operations: associated types (`iterator_category`, `difference_type`, etc.), `==`, postfix `++`, etc.  Also consider supporting random access iterator functionalities if the zipped ranges support them.  We'll come back to this later.

I would also probably implement the `zip` without recursion, to reduce the compile-time overhead of nested template class instantiations.  So the end result roughly looks like this: (not comprehensively tested, may have bugs; for simplicity, only random access ranges are supported)

```
#include <exception>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    using std::begin, std::end;

    template <typename Range>
    struct range_traits {
        using iterator = decltype(begin(std::declval<Range>()));
        using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type;
        using reference = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::reference;
    };

    template <typename... Its>
    class zip_iterator {
    public:
        // technically lying
        using iterator_category = std::common_type_t<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Its>::iterator_category...
        >;
        using difference_type = std::common_type_t<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Its>::difference_type...
        >;
        using value_type = std::tuple<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Its>::value_type...
        >;
        using reference = std::tuple<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Its>::reference...
        >;
        using pointer = std::tuple<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Its>::pointer...
        >;

        constexpr zip_iterator() = default;
        explicit constexpr zip_iterator(Its... its)
            : base_its{its...}
        {
        }

        constexpr reference operator*() const
        {
            return std::apply([](auto&... its) {
                return reference(*its...);
            }, base_its);
        }
        constexpr zip_iterator& operator++()
        {
            std::apply([](auto&... its) {
                (++its, ...);
            }, base_its);
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr zip_iterator operator++(int)
        {
            return std::apply([](auto&... its) {
                return zip_iterator(its++...);
            }, base_its);
        }
        constexpr zip_iterator& operator--()
        {
            std::apply([](auto&... its) {
                (--its, ...);
            }, base_its);
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr zip_iterator operator--(int)
        {
            return std::apply([](auto&... its) {
                return zip_iterator(its--...);
            }, base_its);
        }
        constexpr zip_iterator& operator+=(difference_type n)
        {
            std::apply([=](auto&... its) {
                ((its += n), ...);
            }, base_its);
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr zip_iterator& operator-=(difference_type n)
        {
            std::apply([=](auto&... its) {
                ((its -= n), ...);
            }, base_its);
            return *this;
        }
        friend constexpr zip_iterator operator+(const zip_iterator& it, difference_type n)
        {
            return std::apply([=](auto&... its) {
                return zip_iterator(its + n...);
            }, it.base_its);
        }
        friend constexpr zip_iterator operator+(difference_type n, const zip_iterator& it)
        {
            return std::apply([=](auto&... its) {
                return zip_iterator(n + its...);
            }, it.base_its);
        }
        friend constexpr zip_iterator operator-(const zip_iterator& it, difference_type n)
        {
            return std::apply([=](auto&... its) {
                return zip_iterator(its - n...);
            }, it.base_its);
        }
        constexpr reference operator[](difference_type n) const
        {
            return std::apply([=](auto&... its) {
                return reference(its[n]...);
            }, base_its);
        }

        // the following functions assume usual random access iterator semantics
        friend constexpr bool operator==(const zip_iterator& lhs, const zip_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return std::get<0>(lhs.base_its) == std::get<0>(rhs.base_its);
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator!=(const zip_iterator& lhs, const zip_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator<(const zip_iterator& lhs, const zip_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return std::get<0>(lhs.base_its) < std::get<0>(rhs.base_its);
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator>(const zip_iterator& lhs, const zip_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return rhs < lhs;
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator<=(const zip_iterator& lhs, const zip_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return !(rhs < lhs);
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator>=(const zip_iterator& lhs, const zip_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs < rhs);
        }
     private:
        std::tuple<Its...> base_its;
    };
}

template <typename... Ranges>
class zip {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ranges) > 0, "Cannot zip zero ranges");
public:
    using iterator = detail::zip_iterator<
        typename detail::range_traits<Ranges>::iterator...
    >;
    using value_type = typename iterator::value_type;
    using reference = typename iterator::reference;

    explicit constexpr zip(Ranges&&... rs)
        : ranges{std::forward<Ranges>(rs)...}
    {
    }
    constexpr iterator begin()
    {
        return std::apply([](auto&... rs) {
            return iterator(rs.begin()...);
        }, ranges);
    }
    constexpr iterator end()
    {
        return std::apply([](auto&... rs) {
            return iterator(rs.end()...);
        }, ranges);
    }
private:
    std::tuple<Ranges...> ranges;
};

// by default, rvalue arguments are moved to prevent dangling references
template <typename... Ranges>
explicit zip(Ranges&&...) -> zip<Ranges...>;
```

Let's hope that [P1858 Generalized pack declaration and usage](https://wg21.link/P1858) gets accepted so that we can eliminate the tons of invocations of `std::apply` ...

## `range`

Similar to `zip`, `range` operates on a tuple basis — the parameters are passed as template arguments, and `tuple_size` is provided.  This would limit the usefulness of it, because runtime ranges (e.g., `range(vector.size())`) are not possible.

You choose to make `range` its own iterator type, which is not without [precedent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin) in the standard library.  However, this will cause confusion once you add more functionality to `range`.

A more sophisticated comparison operator that treats sentinel (end) values specially takes the sign of `step` into account allows for commutative comparison and negative steps.

So the end result may look like this: (concept verification, overflow checking, etc. are omitted for simplicity)

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    class range_iterator {
        T value{0};
        T step{1};
        bool sentinel{false};
    public:
        // lying again
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::intmax_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using reference = T;
        using pointer = T*;

        constexpr range_iterator() = default;
        // sentinel
        explicit constexpr range_iterator(T v)
            : value{v}, sentinel{true}
        {
        }
        explicit constexpr range_iterator(T v, T s)
            : value{v}, step{s}
        {
        }

        constexpr reference operator*() const
        {
            return value;
        }
        constexpr range_iterator& operator++()
        {
            value += step;
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr range_iterator operator++(int)
        {
            auto copy{*this};
            ++*this;
            return copy;
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator==(const range_iterator& lhs, const range_iterator& rhs)
        {
            if (lhs.sentinel && rhs.sentinel) {
                return true;
            } else if (lhs.sentinel) {
                return rhs == lhs;
            } else if (lhs.step > 0) {
                return lhs.value >= rhs.value;
            } else if (lhs.step < 0) {
                return lhs.value <= rhs.value;
            } else {
                return lhs.value == rhs.value;
            }
            // C++20: return (lhs.value <=> rhs.value) == (step <=> 0); from third branch
        }
        friend constexpr bool operator!=(const range_iterator& lhs, const range_iterator& rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }
    };
}

template <typename T>
class range {
    T first{0};
    T last{};
    T step{1};
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = detail::range_iterator<T>;

    explicit constexpr range(T e)
        : last{e}
    {
    }
    explicit constexpr range(T b, T e, T s = T{1})
        : first{b}, last{e}, step{s}
    {
    }
    constexpr iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator{first, step};
    }
    constexpr iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator{last};
    }
    constexpr T size() const
    {
        return (last - first) / step;
    }
};
```

You may also consider implementing `enumerate` based on [Python's](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), which comes in handy when accessing sequences by index:

```
// again, rvalue arguments are copied by default
template <typename Sequence>
auto enumerate(Sequence&& seq)
{
    using std::begin, std::end;
    return zip(range(end(seq) - begin(seq)), std::forward<Sequence>(seq));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @L. F. Your answer is a little bit out of my league for several reasons so I'm going to need some time to digest it, but I'm glad I have new material to learn!

Comment: @mqtthiqs OK, I've finished `ranges`.

Comment: Almost one year after I finally get back around to this. Thanks again @L. F. for this enlightening review, I learned a lot.